# How to build CuraEngine?

Tags: software, slicing, ultimaker-cura

I've been trying to build [CuraEngine](https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine) on Ubuntu following the Github instructions.

The problem is that it lists some requirements:

- Clone the CuraEngine repository;
- Install Protobuf (see below);
- Install [libArcus](https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus).

I'm not sure where should I install Protobuf and libArcus. After several tries and locations I've received several errors during the build process.

Does anyone have a more detailed guide on how to build this engine?

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but a somewhat large workaround.

Have you considered using OctoPrint? Most installations including Ubuntu, which I use, come with cura-engine installed. If not, it can be easily installed from the plugins menu in OctoPrint settings. OctoPrint is a really nice alternative to native software for various printers.

I had the same struggle with Protobuf and libArcus and OctoPrint worked great.

Comment: Have you tried installing using `sudo make install` in the protobuf and libArcus (after running cmake) directories?

Comment: I've tried, but the build does not complete so it is impossible to run the install command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually want to *build* Cura, rather than simply install Cura. If you instead want to install Cura, you can try `sudo apt-get install cura-engine`

*The following instructions were tested on my own Debian 8 (Jessie) distribution; they should be mostly, if not entirely, the same, for Ubuntu. Note that I **did not follow the exact steps** as described on the github/Ultimaker/CuraEngine README.*

Before we begin, let's make a build directory and do everything in there.

```
mkdir ~/Downloads/curabuild
cd ~/Downloads/curabuild
```

The instructions will be broken into

## 1. Install dependencies

Some or all of these may already be installed on your computer. To be sure, we install them anyways:

```
sudo apt-get install git curl libtool dh-autoreconf cmake python3-setuptools python3-dev python3-sip sip-dev
```

## 2. Install protobuf

1. Clone and enter the protobuf git repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf
   cd protobuf
   ```
2. Build and install for C++:

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   ./configure
   make # this will take some time
   sudo make install
   ```
3. Install for Python 3:

   ```
   cd python
   sudo python3 setup.py install
   ```

## 3. Install libArcus

1. Clone and enter the libArcus repository:

   ```
   cd ../..
   git clone https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus
   cd libArcus
   ```
2. Build and install

   ```
   cmake .
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

## 4. Install CuraEngine

1. Clone and enter repository:

   ```
   cd ..
   git clone https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine
   cd CuraEngine
   ```
2. Build and install

   ```
   cmake .
   make # grab a cup of coffee
   sudo make install
   ```

## 5. Celebrate!

If all went well, you're done! You can now use the Cura engine via `CuraEngine`. Enjoy.

Comment: The objective is to build cura engine which runs from the terminal so I can run it from command line, will this end up on installing it without the GUI? That is the objective.

Comment: This will not install the GUI. I believe `sudo apt-get install cura-engine` will not install the GUI either.

Comment: I found I also needed `sudo apt-get install python3-sip-dev` otherwise libArcus would fail on the cmake step.